How to pivot wider with one row?
I need to create a column with the total value for each year. The data I am working with now:
Huc12           Year    Density Value
Accotink Creek  2018    0   18054.121680    
Accotink Creek  2018    1   NA  
Accotink Creek  2018    2   NA  
Accotink Creek  2018    3   NA  
Accotink Creek  2018    4   NA  
Accotink Creek  2018    Total   18054.121680    
Accotink Creek  2019    0   17646.898598    
Accotink Creek  2019    1   NA  
Accotink Creek  2019    2   5.736108    
Accotink Creek  2019    3   16.362691   
Accotink Creek  2019    4   385.123872  
Accotink Creek  2019    Total   18054.121269    

I tried the code below from the link here.
tidy <- tidy |> group_by(Year) |> 
    mutate(Total = Value[Density == 'Total'])  |>
    filter(Density != 'Total')

The error I am getting:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Total = Value[Density == "Total"]`.
ℹ In group 1: `Year = "2018"`.
Caused by error:
! `Total` must be size 1488 or 1, not 248.
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::filter(...)
 9. dplyr:::dplyr_internal_error(...)

I believe the issue is that since the years repeat for each huc12, i.e. the dataset is 7440 columns long, there is some issue arising. The total acreage is the same for each huc12. What I need is:
Huc12           Year    Density Value         Total
Accotink Creek  2018    0   18054.121680  18054.121680  
Accotink Creek  2018    1   NA        18054.121680
Accotink Creek  2018    2   NA        18054.121680
Accotink Creek  2018    3   NA        18054.121680
Accotink Creek  2018    4   NA        18054.121680  
Accotink Creek  2019    0   17646.898598  18054.121269  
Accotink Creek  2019    1   NA        18054.121269
Accotink Creek  2019    2   5.736108      18054.121269  
Accotink Creek  2019    3   16.362691     18054.121269  
Accotink Creek  2019    4   385.123872    18054.121269      


Please provide reproducible example for your date (you can use dput()).

If the Total entries accurately reflect the sums for the non-total levels; then you can just throw them away first, and resum.
library(tidyverse)

some_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Huc12, ~Year, ~Density, ~Value,
  "Accotink Creek", 2018, "0", 18054.12168,
  "Accotink Creek", 2018, "1", NA,
  "Accotink Creek", 2018, "2", NA,
  "Accotink Creek", 2018, "3", NA,
  "Accotink Creek", 2018, "4", NA,
  "Accotink Creek", 2018, "Total", 18054.12168,
  "Accotink Creek", 2019, "0", 17646.898598,
  "Accotink Creek", 2019, "1", NA,
  "Accotink Creek", 2019, "2", 5.736108,
  "Accotink Creek", 2019, "3", 16.362691,
  "Accotink Creek", 2019, "4", 385.123872,
  "Accotink Creek", 2019, "Total", 18054.121269
)

(new_data <- some_data |> filter(Density!="Total") |> 
  mutate(Total = sum(Value , na.rm = TRUE), .by = c(Huc12, Year)))

# to show that the values are there
format(unique(pull(new_data,Total)),digits=11)


tidy <- tidy |> group_by(Year) |> 
mutate(Total = sum(Density, na.rm = T))  |>
filter(Density != Total)

I believe this would do the trick for your dataframe, simply sum the column Density and ignore the NA
